# React - как получить data-attribute у текущего объекта

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Мне надо хранить значение "выбран ли элемент" для каждого элемента. Для этого я использую `data-attribute` и вставляю это в jsx в самом элементе. Каким образом можно обратиться к значению `"data-selected"` из `className`?

Как обратиться к значению из функции, вызываемой ивентом - я знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы используете для этого data-attribute?

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов а что для этого использовать? К тому же, я бы хотел научиться использовать data-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше создать компонент для представления региона. В компонент передавать пропсы, например `<Region selected={true} onClick={/** */} />`, а в самом компоненте уже, в зависимости от пропсов, присваивать те или иные классы.

```
const Region = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.option} ${props.selected ? styles.selected : ''}`}
  );
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема data-attribute? Почему ее не стоит использовать? Как по мне, с data-attribute это реализуется более элегантно

Comment: @Coretex, чтобы передать данные из родительского компонента в дочернюю компоненту используются пропсы. Так как в реакте принято во всем использовать компонентный подход, ваш случай - не исключение